# Where to gear up as an elemental (windy) druid?

Tags: diablo-ii

I used to search articles on Internet where items that will suit me should drop, but it looks I do something wrong, or maybe I should increase my MF first.... idk.

So basically I'm 71 lvl windy druid, and have my killing speed on Hell Act 2 is not really enough (Tornado has 2000+ damage). From endgame items I have only boots (Waterwalk) the rest of the stuff is worse. Armor and Headpiece -  Stealth and Lore appropriately. Weapon - Zephyr.

I decided to step back from progressing Hell a bit and farm something on Nightmare (Sewers in Act 2, Durance of Hate, Meph and sometimes Andy). Currently I have 30 MF :(

What do you suggest? I think I should I get more MF items, but were? What farming locations are good? Should I also change /players at some point? Killing Meph at players 8 didn't bring me something useful, unfortunately.

Comment: more MF is definitely going to help more if you can do it without dropping damage, unfortunately I don't know much about druid to help out, but you can use general MF gear, socketed shako, nagles, chances, gold wrap, war travs, mf charms, etc.

Comment: At this moment I have 1 small charm with +3 MF what is ridiculously low. None of my gear or saved gear contain MF as well. That's why I'm trying to figure out is it only my unluckiness or I should pay attention where to farm and at which difficulty. Eventually any MF gear will suit

Comment: Luckily the +6/7% small charm affix is relatively low ilvl so you can afford to drop the difficulty (such as to nightmare mode) in order to boost MF%.  Worst case is you can find some socketed helm and armor and stick perfect topaz into them.  Also look into farming the cow level, just avoid killing the king so you can repeatedly open the portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're going to farm for runes or socketed maces, there's no reason for you to stop progressing if you can.

There is very little in Nightmare that will help you, item wise. Your end game hell items are rune based runewords for spell casting druids.

You need to farm runes (hell sewers) and torches (hell boss farming). Level 60+ in nightmare, you should do as many +players as you can if you're farming in nightmare. Just because something didn't drop for you with +players, doesn't mean it's not worth it to do.

Diablo 2 is all about that grind, so keep at it!

Comment: At this moment I'm in act 2, so farmed a bit Andariel (Hell) and it brought some results! Replaced amulet, hands, armor and a lot of class related stuff. Killing Andariel on Hell difficulty also gives me tons of exp. So this looks at least something, some hope :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some easy methods to buff your gear:

Lore - OrtSol - Helmet: +1 to all skills, %30 Lightres

Smoke - NefLum - Armor: 50% to all res

Spirit - TalThulOrtAmn - +2 to all skills, some nice stats

Rhyme - ShaelEth - Shield: 25% all res, cannot be frozen, 25% mf, faster block rate

Ancients Pledge - RalOrtTal - Shield: 50% all res

You can easily kill nightmare or hell countess to find most of the runes. From the runes above only Lum and Shael might be somewhat hard to find. But do around 10 Hell countess runs on players 1 and you should be good.

Most of your good gear will come from Hell Mephisto. So you should get the basic items up and get yourself a good map. How do you do that? Mephisto is in Durance Level 3. Your waypoint is at level 2. It should be close to the entrance to level 3 and that is considered to be a good map. You reset your map by switching difficulty e.g. going from a hell game to a normal. So once you found your map, you should not reset it. At hell mephisto you can find things like Shako, Skin of Viper, Stormshield, Maras Amulet, Stone of Jordan and all the good stuff.

If you don't care so much for your character and want to gear up quickly in general, you should consider creating a mf character, that is able to quickly teleport and kill hell meph. The items you find with her, you can later use on your druid.

Comment: I am following your proposal, already got Spirit and Rhyme and feels good. Planning to get Smoke soon. At this point I have issues dealing with Physical immune. For example in Arcanum Sanctuary it is truly a nightmare. Can you suggest something?

Comment: I know that Druid struggles with phys immunes. You have only hurricane against them. Try to avoid them as good as you can. Get yourself a teleport staff (2 handed staff with ~ 30/30 Teleport charges). You press W to quickly change to your secondary gear, teleport and switch back. You can buy a staff like that from Ormus on normal. It may cost around 100k.

Comment: I suppose you don't have Reapers Toll. Its an item for your merc that has a chance to cast decreptify. It boosts your physical damage by 50%. You might find it in hell if you are lucky.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to pass Arcanum Sanctuary pretty easy, with Act 2 hierling. Was not rushing and carefully caught all ghosts on my way